# How to update a variable in a nested lambda function (C++)

Tags: c++, lambda, nested

I have two lambda functions.

```
    void func1 ( const std::function< void( std::string ) >& handler );
    void func2 ( const std::function< void( std::string ) >& handler );

    int main()
    {
      func1( []( std::string str1 ) {
        int a = std::stoi( str1 );
        func2( [&a]( std::string str2 ) {
           a += std::stoi( str2 );
        } );

        // a = ?
       });
    }
```

My question is: a = ?

1. std::stoi( str1 ).
2. std::stoi( str1 ) + std::stoi( str2 ).

Comment: What is current value of a?

Comment: What is the output you are getting? the vale of a?   Don't ask us to execute your program :/

Comment: You aren't actually calling either lambda function so a has no value.  Do you plan to call the functions immediately after creating them or sometime later?

Comment: show us definition of func1 and func2 to get correct answer.

Comment: Sorry for let you confused. I simplified my codes here because I found this issue blocked me. 'a' is internal variable in the first lambda function, and want to update 'a' in the second lambda function and return the updated 'a'. I removed the code returning 'a'.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: I want to call them immediately.

Comment: @ShivendraAgarwal: OK, I will try to define them more clearly.

Comment: @Jeff: If you just want to call 2nd lambda why don't you just declare and execute the lambda there itself, without passing it to funct2.

` [&a]( std::string str2 ) {
     a += std::stoi( str2 );
  }  (str1) ; `

Comment: @ShivendraAgarwal: As I said, here I simplified my code here. In my actual code, I have to update 'a' using the 2nd function, but I have to handle 'a' in the 1st function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is truly this simple regarding the lambdas and you actually call the second one (once), variable `a` should be equal to `std::stoi( str1 ) + std::stoi( str2 )`.

Variable `a` is passed to the inner lambda by reference which means it's changes inside the lambda will be reflected in the scope of the outer lambda,

> When accessing a variable, accesses its captured copy (for the
>   entities captured by copy), or the original object (for the entities
>   captured by reference).

according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) reference.

This can be shown using a simple test in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    auto f1 = []()
    {
        int var = 5;
        auto f2 = [&var]() {var--;};
        f2();
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
    };

    f1();
}
```

Here `f1()` declares a variable `var` that is passed to `f2` by reference. `f2` decrements `var` and the value of `var` after calling `f2` becomes 4.

Comment: Your code seems similar with my code. Your code works well, but mine does not. I will check mine further.

Comment: It is like 'var' is still 5 instead of 4.

Comment: Are you using exact same program? For me it's 4.

Comment: "My code" means the above code in my question, not your program. I tried your code, and it worked fine. It's 4.

Comment: A nested lambda based on your question gives the same outcome as in my post. I can post that and that is the answer to your question, I'd think so. What I'm not sure about is how to make it into functions like in your code, how are you calling these? I'm still new to C++.

Comment: I don't think this will work unless you at least add {} next to function declarations. Also, I've tried that. But what I can't figure out is how do you pass the strings str1 and str2 into respective lambdas? Again, when I solve your problem using just nested lambdas (and strings) it all works like in my answer. I can add it.

Comment: It's not a declaration. In my above code, I didn't show the func1 body and func2 body. I guess you regards those codes as their bodies, but they are not. str1 and str2 are assigned inside their bodies. In addition, you don't need to add the running result of my codes. I am checking if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`a` will remain to be following in first lambda, as second lambda is declared but never executed (it is just passed in `func2`).

```
std::stoi( str1 )
```

In case you are executing the capture lambda in `func2` definition, the value of `a` will change to:

```
std::stoi( str1 ) + std::stoi( str2 )
```

PS: You need to put an extra parentheses at end of lambda to execute that.

Comment: If it is executed it is passed by reference and my bet is it will change. More [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Consider adding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3) It depends on what func2 does.  How many times does it call handler and with what strings?  Each time it does, a will be incremented